# PHP header refreshes old page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page containing PHP that reloads the page when the user has entered some data with the line

```
header("/../want.php");
```

The reload of the page should look different to the current one since they have entered data (in this example they have completed the want text box and therefore the variable $want has a length of greater than 1) and PHP checks this with a simple database query  which populates variables like this:

```
if(strlen($want)>1){
    include 'includes/complete.php';
}
else if(strlen($whatknow)>1){
    include 'includes/wantbox.php';
}
else{
    include 'includes/compprev.php';
}
?>
```

However, the reload loads wantbox.php instead of complete.php unless they manually click to reload the page, in which case it loads complete.php.

Why is this happening? It's almost like the PHP code isn't checking the IF statement with the header reload, only with a manual refresh.

Comment: To redirect you use `header("Location: ../want.php");`. You're missing `Location:`.

Comment: Variables aren't preserved when you redirect. You need to use session variables.

Answer (score 2):

## What do you need:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

You're missing `Location:`

http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php